# How to make a division show/hide when I mouseenter/mousexit on a division?

Tags: jquery, hover, division, mouseenter, mouseout

I want to make like that when click/mouseenter on a icon, a division will come out, and when I mouseexit that expanded division, that division will go hide.

I made a script, but it is not working properly:

```
$("#userpanel").hide();
$("#user").mouseenter(function () 
{
    $("#userpanel").fadeIn("slow").css({"top":"185px","left":p+"px;"});
});
$("#userpanel").mouseout(function () 
{
    $("#userpanel").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: You spelled `mouseenter` wrong.  http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: well ,its not an issue, that is my typing mistake.. the code is running successfully ,but the  output is not as i expected,i am looking for do you have any new code that make what i want ,go to amazon.com . when you mouse enter on login,then a div will come out and when you mouse out from that div ,that expanded div goes invisible .. thats what i want,thanks anyway, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mouseleave instead of mouseexit?  Not sure where you're running into issues.  Please explain how it's not doing what you want it to.

Additionally, you've coded that mouseenter #user makes the #userpanel visible.  But then when the mouse leaves #userpanel, #userpanel disappears.  So someone would have to first mouseenter the userpanel, then mouseleave the userpanel.  Is that the issue?

Comment: go to amazon.com . when you mouse enter on login,then a div will come out and when you mouse out from that div ,that expanded div goes invisible .. thats what i want,thanks anyway, appreciate it

Comment: have you tried to change this: $("#userpanel").mouseout to $("#userpanel").mouseleave?  or even better: $(document).on('mouseleave', '#userpanel', function(){

Comment: Make sure that you don't have jquery crashing anywhere: inspect element in chrome and look for a red x on the inspector panel.

Comment: its perfect but on amazon.com when you mouse on anywhere instead of login or that extended div ,(after mouse hovering on loging) that extended div was disappearing ,thats what i want